# Dynamically obtain data for HTML5 Graphic

Tags: html

On my Website I have tables of data that is stored on a database. Also, I use HTML5 in order to generate graphics relative to those data. While there are some general use graphics, I also want users to see how some specific data has evolved in time.

Currently, in order to see that data, you need to click on a link at each value, leading to another page with only the graphic. What I want to do is that an user may hover the mouse over the link, and the graphic will appear.

However, I must only send the data to the user after he hovers the mouse, and probably with some wait time before doing so, so that if he passes the mouse over the table it won't start sending multiple graphs to him. Someone has any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using Ajax.

Comment: would be nice if you share your soulution with us.